# Use Classic Visual Composer code after WP Update to 5.0.2 in Salient Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working a WordPress website using Salient theme and a plugin called Salient Visual Composer. Visual Composer (VC) had the option to see the classic mode e.g. with a code like: ''[vc_row type="in_container" full_screen_row_position="middle"'' before WordPress was updated to version 5.0+. An example below where you can see the button:
[image: Classic Mode]
<sub>(source: [standinginourpower.com](http://standinginourpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Screenshot_3.jpg))</sub>

After the update, all the VC content was automatically moved out of the VC into the content section. Additionally, the classic mode button has disappeared and I can't copy and paste the code from the content and paste it into VC. 
[image: Classic Mode]
<sub>(source: [standinginourpower.com](http://standinginourpower.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Screenshot_2.jpg))</sub>

Any solution?

On other websites, I have uninstalled VC and installed the latest version. I am not sure if this solution will work in this case since the Visual Composer plugin seems to have been adapted to the template salient.

This is an example of the classic mode code:
[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row type="in_container" full_screen_row_position="middle" equal_height="yes" scene_position="center" text_color="dark" text_align="left" overlay_strength="0.3" shape_divider_position="bottom" shape_type=""]

What I expect is to be able to copy an paste the code and make it easy for me to edit the page using VC. Otherwise, it will be difficult to work with or even necessary to re-do the page. Something that I want to avoid.

Comment: Have you installed Classic Editor plugin?

Comment: Yes,  it didn't work. Some elements from Salient Visual Composer were gone when using the normal VC plugin

Comment: You can try replacing WordPress with [Calm Press](https://calmpress.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Salient wrote this guide in order to provide a solution to this issue. You can [click here](http://themenectar.com/docs/salient/wordpress-5-0-update-guide/) to read the documentation. The solution was to install the plugin "Classic Editor".